# UDP tuning linux

Tags: linux, networking, udp, packet-loss

I have C application which transmits UDP stream. It works well in most of servers, but its crazy on few servers.

I have **100 Mbps** network connection say **eth1** on server. Using this network I usually transmit (TX) around **10-30 Mbps** UDP streams, and this network connection will have around **100-300 Kbps** RX to server. I have other network connection say **eth0** in server from which C application receives UDP streams and forwards to 100 Mbps network connection, **eth1**.

My application uses **blocking** `sendto()` function to transmit UDP packets in **eth1**. Packets are of variable length, from 17 bytes to maximum 1333 bytes. But most of time, more than 1000 bytes.

The problem is: sometime `sendto` function blocks on **eth1** for huge time around 1 second. This happens once in every 30 seconds to 3 minutes. When `sendto` blocks, I will have lot of UDP packets buffered in UDP receive buffer from **eth0** by kernel, from where C application receive packets. Once `sendto` returns from long blocking call on **eth1**, C application will have lot of buffered packets to transmit from **eth0**. And then C application transmits all these buffered packets with next `sendto` calls. This will **create spike in rate** at other endpoint which receives UDP stream from **eth1**. This will create **Z** like rate graph at other endpoint. So this **Z like spike in rate** is my problem.

I have tried to increase `wmem_default` from around **131 KB** to **5 MB** in kernel setting to overcome spike. And setting this resolves my issue of spike. Now I don't get **Z like spike in rate** at other endpoint, but I got new issue. The new issue is: I get lot of packet losses in place of spike. I think it may be due to send buffer of **eth1** accumulating lot of packets to send while sending current packet from **eth1** takes lot of time (this is why may be `sendto` blocking long). And at next instant when NIC sends all accumulated packets from send buffer in short time, this may be causing network congestion and I may be getting lot of packet losses instead of spike.

So, this is second problem. But I think root cause is: why sometime NIC pauses for long time while sending traffic, once in every 30 seconds to 3 minutes?

May be I need to look in **TX ring buffer of driver of eth1**? When socket send buffer gets full due to NIC not transmitting all in time (due to random long TX pauses), then next call to `sendto` blocks for room in socket send buffer, does that also blocks for room in **driver TX ring buffer**?

Please dont tell me that UDP is unreliable and we can't control packet losses. I know that its unreliable and UDP packets can be lost. But I am sure still we can do something to minimize packet losses.

**EDIT**

I have tried to increase `wmem_default` from around **131 KB** to **5 MB** in kernel setting to overcome spike. **And also** I have removed blocking `sendto` call. Now I use like: `sendto(sockfd, buf, len, MSG_DONTWAIT ,dest_addr, addrlen);` with large send buffer using `wmem_default`. Also I am not getting any `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` errors on `sendto` due to large send buffer, but still packets loosing in place of spike.

**EDIT**

As non-blocking `sendto` call with huge `wmem_default`, and as NO any `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` errors from `sendto`, spikes have been removed because no much packets accumulating in receive buffer of **eth0**. I think its possible solution from application side. But main problem is why NIC slows every few moments? What can be possible reasons? While it resumes from long TX pause, and may be it will have lot of packets accumulated in send buffer, which will be sent as burst next moment and congesting network so lot of packet losses.

**More update**

I use same this C application to transmit locally in machine (127.0.0.1), and I never get any spikes or packet losses problems locally.

Comment: Simply blocking on send seems bad here. You'll want to use some sort of async queue. But really, this is way to broad, especially without any code to go on.

Comment: It is a good question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I updated question. I am not using blocking call now, but still packets loosing.

Comment: @UDPLover That's the thing: you are supposed to lose packets in UDP when there is network congestion *or* the NIC queueing discipline tells to drop a packet.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin thanks for information. How can I know if NIC queuing discipline dropping packets? Are packets discarded at lower level queues, after having been buffered in socket send buffer?

Comment: As this is 100 Mbps connection, I am not overwhelming transfer rate. Because at next moment I get burst coming out of NIC.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Re-open the question please.

Comment: @maxim agreed, it looks better; done!

Comment: The timers looks suspiciously to be within the timers linux uses for ARP, see the net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_interval,net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_stale_time and possibly others

Comment: gc_interval is 30 and gc_stale_time is 60

Comment: @nos The all values in `default/` and `eth1/` are same as default values indicated in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/arp.7.html

Comment: @nos app_solicit is 0.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is: sometime sendto function blocks on eth1 for huge time around 1 second.

Blocking `sendto` may block, surprisingly.

> The problem is: sometime sendto function blocks on eth1 for huge time around 1 second.

It could be that [IP stack is performing path MTU discovery](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html):

> While MTU discovery is in progress, initial packets  from  datagram  sockets  may be dropped.  Applications using UDP should be aware of this and not take it into account for their packet retransmit strategy.

---

> I have tried to increase wmem_default from around 131 KB to 5 MB in kernel setting to overcome spike.

Be careful with increasing buffer sizes. After a certain limit increasing buffer sizes only increases the amount of queuing and hence delay, leading to the infamous [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat).

---

You may also play around with [NIC Queuing Disciplines](http://www.coverfire.com/articles/queueing-in-the-linux-network-stack/), they are responsible for dropping outgoing packets.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So while MTU discovery happening, does NIC stops TXing UDP packets? If so, do I need to turn it off? If so, how can I turn it off?

Comment: Thanks for information about bufferbloat, usually I never set `SO_SNDBUF` or increase `wmem_default`, I keep it linux default. But for this special problem I needed to do this.

Comment: @UDPLover Read `man ip(7)` for more details how to control MTU discovery through that link I provided for you.

Comment: One more thing, can packets be dropped at lower level queues, after having been queued in socket send buffer?

Comment: @UDPLover Yep, that's what qdisc's do. Again, read that link about queuing disc..

Comment: I checked with tcpdump, I dont get any ICMP activity when there are spikes or packet losses. If I get ICMP activity then that can mean PMTU in progress, but never seen any ICMP activity.

Comment: Last step to resolve this will be to retire that server completely.